# Line rewrapping on zoom

Tags: html

Is there a way to tell the browser to rewrap paragraphs when a page is magnified? Without rewrapping the user needs to side scroll back and forth, making the text hard to read comfortably.

Comment: In my experience it's very difficult to manage zoom (get reliable data) in browsers. The way I manage text resizing - and this automatically re-flows text ( which is what it sounds like you're looking for ) - is to offer the user 2 buttons - eg. 1 with a small A and the other with a bigger A, then increase/decrease the font size for them when they click/tap the button. If they zoom they still have the problem with needing to scroll but you have made zooming unnecessary ( for text at least ). Obviously you could use sliders/magnifying glass icons etc instead of buttons.